# Ambiguous use of appendInterpolation - Why?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When using CustomStringConvertible structs, regular String interpolation works fine, however because Text (SwiftUI) uses LocalizedString interpolation, it doesn't, and requires you to either fully append `.description`, or to use `Text(verbatim: ...)` or `Text(String(describing...))`

Until(?) Apple harmonises the interpolation of String and LocalizedString, it seemed an easy enough fix to create an extension to make interpolation work on CustomStringConvertibles in an intuitive way. e.g.

```
extension LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation {
   public mutating func appendInterpolation<S: CustomStringConvertible>(_ convertible: S) {
      self.appendInterpolation(convertible.description)
   }
}
```

This now means Text works as expected.
e.g.

```
struct Car: CustomStringConvertible {
    var model: String
    var description: String 
}
var car: Car = Car(model: "Ford Ka", description: "Dubiously named oddity")
```

and in your views:
 `Text("\(car)")`
outputs the description as above.
Great!

**but** ... any other Text interpolations now produce an error : *"Ambiguous use of appendInterpolation"*
e.g.

```
let a = 1
Text("\(a)").   <--- error: Ambiguous use of appendInterpolation
```

Removing the extension above immediately resolves the error.
I would love to understand why, as I've been scratching my head on this for a while.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call is ambiguous between your overload of `appendInterpolation`, and [this builtin overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/localizedstringkey/stringinterpolation/appendinterpolation(_:)-378v9), which takes a `_FormatSpecifiable`.

Since both methods are generic, Swift can't decide which one is "better", and tells you that it is ambiguous.

You can make your method non-generic instead:

```
extension LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation {
   public mutating func appendInterpolation(_ convertible: any CustomStringConvertible) {
      self.appendInterpolation(convertible.description)
   }
}
```

This causes Swift to always prefer your method, which might mess up some localised string keys. If you had `Text("This is a number: \(someInt)")`, `Text` will look for a localisation key of "This is a number: %lld". But if it calls your method, it doesn't know to replace the interpolation with `%lld`, and from my experiments, it replaces it with `%@` instead.

---

Just for the fun of it, let's try conforming to `_FormatSpecifiable`! (Since it is prefixed with an underscore, this is non-stable API and will probably break)

```
extension Car: _FormatSpecifiable {
    var _arg: String {
        description
    }
    
    var _specifier: String {
        "%@"
    }
}
```

The `_specifier` property is presumably used to compute the actual localised string key. For example, if it were `"I have a \(car)"`, and `_specifier` returns `%@`, the localisation key would be `"I have a %@"`.

This also allows you to do weird things like this:

```
Text("\(car, specifier: "%p")") // shows a pointer to car
```

(This is calling [this other overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/localizedstringkey/stringinterpolation/appendinterpolation(_:specifier:)))

Comment: Brilliant! Thankyou. I had looked for other overloads, but did not realise that two generic overloads would clash - even if the generic restrictions were different and non overlapping.

Comment: @Disco An `Int` satisfies the generic constraints of both methods - it conforms to both `_FormatSpecifiable` and `CustomStringConvertible`. That's what makes it ambiguous. This has nothing to do with whether the generic constraints are overlapping.